How to improve shortest path results with Dijkstra/A* on a hexagonal mesh
I am working with traversable polygons and need to calculate the shortest path across them. To do this, I generated a hexagonal mesh over the polygons, extracted the edges, and applied both Dijkstra and A* algorithms.
However, the resulting paths often feature unnatural angles that do not resemble a "natural" shortest path.
Here are the specifics:
The hexagons in the mesh are relatively small.
I’ve set a uniform cost of 1 for all edges.
To address the issue, I tried using ST_Simplify and ST_ChaikinSmoothing to smooth the paths. While larger simplification values yield straighter lines, they come with drawbacks, such as over-simplifying the path.
Simplyfied pgr_routing Query:
WITH path AS (
    SELECT edge, seq
    FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM mesh',
        (SELECT source FROM mesh ...),
        (SELECT target FROM mesh ...)
    )
)
SELECT
    ST_AsGeoJSON(
        ST_ChaikinSmoothing(
            ST_Simplify(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(mesh.geom)), 1, true),
            3, true
        )
    )
FROM path
JOIN mesh ON mesh.id = path.edge;



Since all hexagon edges have the same cost assigned there are thousands of possible combinations for a shortest path with equal total costs!
As assigning meaningful cost values over your hex grid is non-trivial, and likely defeating the purpose of your undertaking, one option is to use pgr_ksp (K Shortest Paths) to retrieve the K shortest paths for your query points, of which you can then choose the one with a minimum value of an absolute measure.
Edit:
One such measure could be the least ST_FrechetDistance to a straight line between the start and end vertices of your query.

There are a few more involved approaches used in motion detection and routing to do just that, but you could try to select the one path with the least geographical ST_Length (using GEOGRAPHY).

Thank you! I like your ideas. I tried both of them, but unfortunately, I still get more or less the same result. I queried just 10 paths from pgr_ksp, but only 2-4 of them have a different Frechet distance. I think it would work if I queried more than 10 shortest paths, but I need to keep the time in mind as the user would wait too long to get the shortest path. I think I will try applying higher costs to the lines that lie near the outer rings of the traversable polygons.

Give ST_HausdorffDistance a chance, it is less sensitive to incompatible vertex counts - but not optimal, ether. In general, this whole approach heavily depends on getting a significant sample size (K) of paths. If that is not an option, assigning meaningful cost values is of course an option; either an inverse distance cost to polygons to favor paths that tend to be midway between any polygon, or (normal) distance to follow polygon edges more closely (if one were pedantic, this would likely be the more precise shortest paths)

I get really good results from a 500-path sample, but it takes 10 minutes to query, even with the bbox strategy. If I apply higher costs on edges that lie near the rings of the multipolygon, I get faster results, and it's better than doing nothing, but still not great. If every edge gets a higher cost in a 'corridor' because my buffer for the rings is too high, this solution doesn't improve anything.
